# Adding data to a collection with unbounded wildcard type

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

What is the difference between the two? Why can't I add data to the first one, but can add to the second one?

```
   HashMap<?, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
   map.put(Integer.class, 1); // Error

   HashMap<Class<?>, Object> map2 = new HashMap<>();
   map2.put(Integer.class, 1); // Ok
```

Comment: Change `list.add(Integer.class);` to `list2.add(Integer.class);` on last line, and surprise surprise.. It works. And you loose my vote.

Comment: @rohit let's close it using the new "typo" off-topic reason...

Comment: @Bohemian Oh! That's a new addition. Just used that ;)

Comment: But I thought only the second part of the question has a typo. Just remove the second part, instead of closing the question!

Comment: Thanks, I did not see the typo. Removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first case, the type of keys is **any concrete** (i.e. the same for all keys of map), so we can't insert anything except `null`, because we don't know this type. (So `map` can hold a value of type `HashMap<Integer, Object>` or `HashMap<String, Object>` or else).

In second case, the type of keys is `Class` with `any concrete` type-argument, **that may differ from one key to another**. So you cat put into this map a key-value pair, where key is any instance of `Class` (`Class<Integer>`, `Class<String>`,...), but you can't put keys with other types (for example, `Integer`, `String`,...)

Answer (score 0):

Go through this tutorial,this might help you understand wild cards and their uses.

http://ted-gao.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/Java%20Generics

and for difference between List and map ::

```
Java map: An object that maps keys to values. A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can  map to at most one value.

Java list: An ordered collection (also known as a sequence).The user of this interface has precise control over where in the list each element is inserted. The user can access elements by their integer index (position in the list), and search for elements in the list.
```